# Go to the URL when clicked on Leaflet geometry

Tags: leaflet

I have a very simple issue: 
I have a rectangle. I would like to link a website to that rectangle which will be opened on click on a new web browser window.
I do not want to apply pop-up option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a click handler to your rectangle and open a new window/tab in the handler function:

```js
// Create rectangle and add to map
var rectangle = new L.Rectangle([
    [54.559322, -5.767822],
    [56.1210604, -3.021240]
]).addTo(map);

// Attach clickhandler
rectangle.on('click', function(){
    // Open new window/tab
    window.open('www.example.org','_blank');
});
```

Comment: Thank you @iH8 for your prompt and efficient answer! It is working smooth!